# How to get selected item of windows 8.1 Raddatagrid telerik control using a button

Tags: windows-8.1, win-universal-app, telerik-window

I using a RadDataGrid on an application Windows 8.1. The grid has 3 columns: Name, description and template column with a "select" button. When user press Select button, I'd like that program shows an message with id of selected item

This is my code.

```
<Grid:RadDataGrid  x:Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<Grid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
    <Grid:DataGridTextColumn CanUserFilter="False" CanUserEdit="False" PropertyName="Name" Header="Name">
            </Grid:DataGridTextColumn>
            <Grid:DataGridTextColumn CanUserFilter="False" CanUserEdit="False" PropertyName="Description" Header="Description">
            </Grid:DataGridTextColumn>
            <Grid:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserFilter="False" CanUserEdit="False">
                <Grid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Button x:Name="BtnSelect" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="BtnSelect_OnClick"></Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                </Grid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
        </Grid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</Grid:RadDataGrid.Columns>    
</Grid:RadDataGrid>
```

Code-behind

```
    private void BtnSelect_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ?
    }
```